# Porque no funciona el evento click en un ion-item?

Tags: ionic

Tengo un ion-list dentro de un ion-menu en el cual intento hacer click sobre los items que contiene un ion-content para cambiar de pantalla pero no funciona

```
<ion-menu side="start" contentId="first">
 <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title>My app menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-header>

 <ion-content id="first">
   <ion-list>
     <ion-item (click)="users()" detail>
       <ion-icon name="person" class="ion-margin"></ion-icon> Users
     </ion-item>
     <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
     <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
     <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
   </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

En mi ts tengo lo siguiente

```
constructor(
  private _menu: MenuController,
  private _router: Router) {
}

openFirst() {
  this._menu.enable(true, 'first');
  this._menu.open();
}

users(){
  this._router.navigate(['users']);
}
```

Y la versión de Ionic es la 5.4.15

Comment: agrega tu codigo que esta en el ts de tu componente para saber si se encuentra el error ahi, el html por lo que veo esta bien

Comment: tambien menciona que version de ionic usas y sube tambien el archivo de rutas para saber si el problema viene desde ahi

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta @ASASCED

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de probar tu codigo sin el menu y funciona perfectamente, necesitaría ver mas para saber cual puede ser el error, estas usando el menu como un componente? si podes subir un poco mas de informacion lo puedo volver a probar.
Sino podes agregar tambien podes agregar un debugger adentro de la funcion users a ver si la esta ejecutando al menos

```js
users(){
  debugger;
  this._router.navigate(['users']);
}
```

Comment: Si se está utilizando como un componente y no ejecuta la función

Comment: bien, estas implementando bien el componente? y lo otro, esas funciones estan en el archivo ts del menu no?

Comment: Si están las funciones en el ts de menu y el componente está siendo utilizado en el home component

Comment: bueno voy a precisar mas codigo entonces

Comment: Detecté que al momento de abrir el menu, el ion-content toma la clase menu-content-open la cual tiene la propiedad pointer-events:none; que es la que está causando todo el relajo

Comment: proba esto, el menu instancialo como componente en el app.component.html solamente, eso lo va a instanciar en todas las paginas asi que tenes que sacarlo del home, si lo tenes instanciado en varios lugares va a funcionar mal

Answer (score 0):

Añade alguna clase para modificar "pointer-events", también puedes añadir en app.component.scss lo siguiente:

```
.menu-content-open {
pointer-events: visible !important;
}
```